# The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck. Unknown reason

Tags: crash, minidumps, bsod

I have built my first rig after a while, everything works just fine, but the system randomly crashes (no BSOD, just restarts itself), and can't find the reason T_T. Here is the Minidump file

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C0370AD63AC42088!4670&authkey=!ACHeu4nigMQXzHg&ithint=file%2cdmp

How could I fix this?

Comment: I haven't looked at the dump file, but are you running your system overclocked by any chance? Also check to make sure that all cables and other connections (RAM, peripherals, etc.) are secure.

Comment: Yes, it is OC-d, an i5 2500K @ 4.2GHz, but I don't think that is the reason, otherwise there would be BSOD as far as I know. Since I have never met with this bugcheck I'm not sure, but can a software cause this? Like a not properly installed office?

Answer (score 0):

**1st** - check your computer's physical push buttons and make sure it is not a physical issues such as bad push button that closes the circuit even after you done pushing it.

**2nd** - Using dump file I can't say much about the condition because sometime dump file misbehaves depending on the issue. But you can physically remove the RAM and re install it and check whether error occurs again.

**3rd** - If you can check processor temperature using BIOS check whether it stays between 50 - 70 Celsius (more like 60) If you can't see the temperature in BIOS then please check your Thermal Paste is good ( **last option**, If you are certain about the Thermal paste between processor and heat sink is good or newly added removing heat sink will make the thermal past useless)

Comment: The temperature is under 75 Celsius under full load, the physical buttons are fine, and the thermal paste is fine as well. Btw, since I have never met with this bugcheck I'm not sure, but can a software cause this? Like a not properly installed office?

Comment: No It can't be, as long as you are not messing with your operating system or BIOS I don't think it's due to bad installation of office. Try a live CD of ubuntu or any other OS version and see whether the error occurs even then, If it is so then It's a hardware problem Not OS/Software issue.

Comment: Decreased the OC from 4.2 Ghz to 3.8 Ghz and it seems stable now, however it would be better on 4.2...

Comment: Now check with the average core temperature, If it's lower than before then we can assume that It's a over heating issue when OC, or Maybe Its due to conflict between your ram frequency and Clock speed. If you are not working your computer for heavy processing purposes then you don't have to do OC . normally when you OC it makes cores unstable and power inefficient even though there's an option for OC.